# Laravel 5.7 Export File to Excel

Tags: laravel, export, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to export my Resident List into Excel. It downloads into an excel file but when I open the file it has nothing in it.

Here's the code for my Controller:

```
public function export()
{
    return Excel::download(new Resident, 'Resident.xlsx');
}
```

Here's my routes:

```
Route::get('/export', 'ImportController@export');
```

Here's my blade file button for the export:

```
<a href="{{ url('/export') }}"><button class="btn btn-primary">Export</button></a>
```

Here's my model:

```
public function collection()
{
    return Resident::all();
}
```

Comment: You are not sending any data. You are just creating an empty Resident

Answer (score 0):

You can Try Using get()

```
public function collection()
{
    return Resident::get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to download file with below code

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class ResidentExport implements FromCollection
{
    public function collection()
    {
        return Resident::all();  
    }
}
```

Then import ResidentExport in your controller

```
public function export()
{
    return Excel::download(new ResidentExport, 'Resident.xlsx');
}
```